# Laravel phpunit testing controller which returns view with data

Tags: laravel, tdd, phpunit

Am trying to adapt TDD on laravel, but am getting trouble to test controller which queries a collection of records and returns view with data when I run my test it returns an error message that trying to get the id of undefined property

// my test

```
namespace Tests\Unit;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;


class JobApplicationTest extends TestCase
{
use WithoutMiddleware;
/** @test */
public function user_can_see_all_open_positions()
{
    // when user visit apply for a job page
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
   $response = $this->get(route('positions.open'));
   $response->assertSuccessful();
   $response->assertViewIs('positions.open.index');
   $response->assertViewHas('positions');
}


}

// My controller

 public function open(Request $request)
{

    //TODO support additional filters & searches

    //initialize query
    $query = Position::query()->which()->are()->open();

    //paginate query result
    $positions = $query->paginate(config('app.defaults.pageSize'));

    $data = [
        'route_title' => 'Open Job Positions',
        'route_description' => 'Available Job Positions',
        'positions' => $positions,
    ];

    return view('positions.open.index', $data);
}
```

so the problem is when I run text it looks view is returned with no data while view references data returned to the controller

error message when running test

> 1) Tests\Unit\JobApplicationTest::user_can_see_all_open_positions
>   ErrorException: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View:
>   /var/www/html/ipf-projects/niajiri/resources/views/pos
>   itions/open/index.blade.php)

---

```
<h3> 
    <a href="{{ route('positions.preview', [
        'id'   => $position->id,
        'slug' => str_slug($position->title)
    ]) }}" class="text-navy"> 
         {!! $position->title !!} - {!! $position->organization->name !!} 
    </a>
</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Within `'positions.open.index'` it is trying to access an `id` property on a non-object.

This could be because your `$query` does not return any `Position` objects (i.e. `$data->positions` returns an empty `Collection`)

When running unit tests it is likely that it is creating a temporary database (`sqlite` by default) which will not be populated with any data. Try adding some `Position`s in your test like so:

```
/** @test */
public function user_can_see_all_open_positions()
{
   // Create Positions
   Position::create([/* Some data here */]);
   Position::create([/* Some data here */]);

   // when user visit apply for a job page
   $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
   $response = $this->get(route('positions.open'));
   $response->assertSuccessful();
   $response->assertViewIs('positions.open.index');
   $response->assertViewHas('positions');
}
```

Comment: i created a position using factory and position is created to the database but the problem still a controller returns view of which the view needs data and on my test i was not able get collection of data returned to controller

$position = factory(Position::class)->create();

Comment: Can you post the content of `positions.open.index`? Are there any instance where you are getting an `->id` prop on an object that isn't of type `Position`?

Comment: <h3>
<a href="{{ route('positions.preview', ['id' => $position->id,'slug'=>str_slug($position->title)]) }}"
                                               class="text-navy">
                                                {!!$position->title!!} - {!!$position->organization->name!!}
                                            </a>
                                        </h3>